# Webapp security Using custom file extensions

Tags: php, apache, security

I've been researching about webapp security for a few days now and I came across a suggestion. Hide php,js,css etc by using different file name extensions. How much does that actually help security wise? Is it worth doing or not? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Security by obscurity" is probably the weakest form of security.

It's debatable that it may be even less secure than no security, due to giving a false sense of security.

Specific to web development, there is no point in hiding your client js and css files. Those files are rendered by the browser, and anyone who views the page can view them.

Also by renaming your php files, you might circumvent any light security your webhosting has enabled for protecting viewing of those files.